# I'm struggling with the WHERE IN query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am not able to use this code. I've echoed the implode (and it works perfectly) but I cannot seem to get it to work with the WHERE IN query.

I've tried echo the import, which works, and the code works perfectly when I remove the WHERE IN, so I know the elements within 'etc etc' are working, too.

```
$filter_category = "SELECT * FROM `youcard_wp`.`bc_term_relationships`
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '57'";
$result_c = $conn90->query($filter_category);
while($row_c = $result_c->fetch_assoc()){
    $category_filter[] = $row_c['object_id'];
}

echo implode(',', $category_filter); // <- works great

$get_offer_list = "
SELECT * FROM `youcard_wp`.`bc_posts`
WHERE `ID` IN ('".implode(',', $category_filter)."')
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'portfolio'
ORDER BY menu_order ASC
";
$result = $conn90->query($get_offer_list);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

etc etc etc...
```

Comment: please show error log

Comment: You put quotes around the whole thing, so it is considered _one_ string value, and not multiple individual ones. `IN (1,2,3)` and `IN ('1,2,3')` are of course two completely different things.

Comment: I don't understand the need for two queries here. If it was me, I'd get rid of all the PHP stuff from the question for now, and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Define "cannot get it to work". Was there a PHP error? Was there an empty result?

Comment: I have to admit (and I know it sounds petty), I'm mystified that you'd accept that answer over mine. Perhaps you haven't understood how poor the accepted answer is by comparison !?!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are surrounding the whole `IN` list with a pair of single quotes, whereas you would need to quote each individual value.

Consider:

```
$get_offer_list = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `youcard_wp`.`bc_posts`
    WHERE 
        `ID` IN ('" .implode("','", $category_filter)."')
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_type = 'portfolio'
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
";
```

If `ID`s are actually numeric values and not strings, then you do not need quotes at all:

```
$get_offer_list = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM `youcard_wp`.`bc_posts`
    WHERE 
        `ID` IN (" .implode(",", $category_filter).")
        AND post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_type = 'portfolio'
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
";
```

Comment: Use prepared statements without exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of that. Instead use this...

```
SELECT x.columns
     , x.you
     , x.actually
     , x.want
  FROM bc_posts x
  JOIN bc_term_relationships y
    ON y.object_id = x.id
 WHERE x.post_status = 'publish'
   AND x.post_type = 'portfolio'
   AND y.term_taxonomy_id = 57
 ORDER 
    BY x.menu_order ASC
```